# overriding default values when using lombok builder

Tags: java, builder, lombok

I am using lombok's builder. To assign the default value to some variables I am trying to use

> @Builder.Default

But the problem is that on using the above annotation, I am no longer able to initialize that value through builder as compiler says can not resolve method while trying to initialize the variable through builder.

So, essentially what I am looking for is a way to set default values and still be able to override when initiating through builder.

Answer (score 4):

My team has been struggling with this annotation failing to work in certain IDE's. Our workaround is to define a constructor with the `@Builder` annotation that sets the defaults if no value was given. For example:

```
public class ExampleClass {

    private final OtherClass otherClassField;

    @Builder
    public ExampleClass(OtherClass otherClass) {
        // if otherClass is null, use a default value
        otherClassField = otherClass != null ? otherClass : new OtherClass();
    }
}
```

As a note, if your class has primitive type fields, you'll need to use the primitive-wrapper types for the constructor arguments to be able to continue to use a `null` value to indicate falling back to the default.

You can also change the constructor access level to `private` to allow instances of this class to only be created using a builder.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. So when you say IDE, do you mean compilation is working fine for you .. but error is just in IDE ? Because for me even compilation is failing if I mark a field as @Builder.Default and then try to initialize it using builder

Comment: Yes, compiling from the command line works fine for me. Compiling/running unit tests from within the IDE (Intellij in our case)  is what wasn't working.

Comment: so you were able to initialize the value through builder even when you have marked them with Builder.default ? Strange :(

Comment: a couple of things, the access level on the constructor can be package to discourage use direct use of the constructor. secondly, this works well with the `@Value` annotation to make the object immutable. In the example above adding `@Value` you could remove the final  marker on the field, and you'd get a getter method generated